# Doctrine Extension Translatable with extends class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a problem with Doctrine Extension Translatable and I hope to find a solution here.

I have 2 class : cardItem and Dish in a single table. Both ot them implement Translatable and Dish extends CardItem.

First question : do I need to implement "Translatable" for Dish class ?

Here a small test that doesn't work and I don't know why :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$repository = $em->getRepository('Project\MyBundle\Entity\Translation\CardItemTranslation');
$dishManager = $this->get('dish_manager');

$dish = $dishManager->find(1);

$repository->translate($dish, 'name', 'en_GB', 'content in english')
    ->translate($dish, 'description', 'en_GB', 'description in english');

$em->persist($dish);
$em->flush();
```

I've got an error : "Uncaught PHP Exception Gedmo\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: "**Entity: Project\MyBundle\Entity\Dish does not translate field - description**"

CardItem.php

```php
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Gedmo\Translatable\Translatable;

/**
 * CardItem
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="card_item", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="index_inserted_at", columns={"inserted_at"})})
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap( {"dish" = "Dish"} )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Project\MyBundle\Repository\CardItemRepository")
 * @Gedmo\TranslationEntity(class="Project\MyBundle\Entity\Translation\CardItemTranslation")
 * @ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
abstract class CardItem implements Translatable {

      /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @Expose
     */
    protected $id;

      /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=200, nullable=true)
     * @Expose
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)
     * @Expose
     */
    protected $description;

    [...]

}
```

Dish.php

```php
/**
 * Dish.
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Project\MyBundle\Repository\DishRepository")
 * @Gedmo\TranslationEntity(class="Project\MyBundle\Entity\Translation\CardItemTranslation")
 */
class Dish extends CardItem implements Translatable
{
     /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @ORM\Column(name="button_label", type="string", length=500, nullable=true)
     * @Expose
     */
    private $buttonLabel;

    ...
}
```

Any idea ?

Thank very much !

Comment: could you list Dish-Entity completeley?

Comment: It's a big entity but I don't know what you want to know exactly. There is no "name" or "description" attributes.

Is it the purpose of your question ?

Comment: Except button_label, there is no other field to translate in Dish entity.

I don't know if it could be the source of this problem but "description" is a text type, not a string unlike "name".

Comment: well the first question is. Have you tried changing its type to string?

Comment: I tried to change but still the same error. According to the documentation, there is no problem with Translatable and text type. 

And by the way, I get the content of description when I do " $dish->getDescription()"

Comment: Next step, try to change the single table in joined : one translation table per entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it works with "JOINED" table. It's little bit difficult to change single_table to joined but it works.